# Unable to show all objects in array on v-for loop, only showing last object

Tags: arrays, json, vue.js, v-for

I'm pulling in some data. I'm grouping this data by key and then trying to print that out in a v-for loop in Vue.

The code looks something like this:

```js
// I initialize an empty array in data
data() {
  return {
    locArray: []
  }
}


// This is done in the api call, in beforeRouteEnter()

const items = data.continental;

Array.prototype.groupBy = function(prop) {
  return this.reduce(function(groups, item) {
    const val = item[prop];
    groups[val] = groups[val] || [];
    groups[val].push(item);
    return groups;
  }, {});
};

for (let i in items) {
  let source = items[i];
  let details = source.details;
  let groupedByLocation = details.groupBy(location);
  vm.locArray = groupedByLocation
}

// This is an example of what the data looks like
{
  data: {
    continental: {
      countryOne: {
        weather: "weatherOne",
        details: [{
          location: "west",
          foods: "foodOne",
          mainCities: [
            "cityOne",
            "cityTwo",
            "cityThree"
          ]
        }]
      },
      countryTwo: {
        weather: "weatherTwo",
        details: [{
          location: "north",
          foods: "foodTwo",
          mainCities: [
            "cityOne",
            "cityTwo",
            "cityThree"
          ]
        }]
      },
      countryThree: {
        weather: "weatherThree",
        details: [{
          location: "north",
          foods: "foodThree",
          mainCities: [
            "cityOne",
            "cityTwo",
            "cityThree"
          ]
        }]
      },
      countryFour: {
        weather: "WeatherFour",
        details: [{
          location: "west",
          foods: "foodFour",
          mainCities: [
            "cityOne",
            "cityTwo",
            "cityThree"
          ]
        }]
      },
      countryfive: {
        weather: "WeatherFive",
        details: [{
          location: "north",
          foods: "foodFive",
          mainCities: [
            "cityOne",
            "cityTwo",
            "cityThree"
          ]
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content">
  <div class="single-entry" v-for="loc in locArray" :key="loc.id">
    <span class="test-wrap">{{ loc }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I `console.log(groupedByLocation)` I get all the data that's supposed to show up, but in v-for I'm only getting the last object in the array.

It seems simple but I'm really stumped.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

> The desired outcome is that I'd like to print all the items that have `location: north` together in a group above and all the items that have `location: west` in a different group below.

Comment: Can you share any working jsFiddle like example (it will be a great help to find out the issue)?

Comment: Your for is `v-for="pos in posArray"`, not `v-for="pos in groupedByPos"`. What's in `posArray`?

Comment: @SajibKhan I've added further details for clarity.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Right. I've added a more detailed example above for clarity. What I'm calling in v-for (this time `locArray`) is being assigned the contents of `groupedByLocation`, which is what prints out correctly in `console.log`

Comment: The desired outcome is that I'd like to print all the items that have `location: north` together in a group above and all the items that have `location: west` in a different group below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you're calling `groupBy` on each iteration of your for loop.

I would solve this [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)ing by `details[0].location` the [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)s of `continental`:

```js
  methods: {
    filterByLocation: function(location) {
      return Object.values(this.continental).filter(v => v.details[0].location === location)
    }
  }
```

Example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    continental: {
      countryOne: {
        weather: "weatherOne",
        details: [{
          location: "west",
          foods: "foodOne",
          mainCities: [
            "cityOne",
            "cityTwo",
            "cityThree"
          ]
        }]
      },
      countryTwo: {
        weather: "weatherTwo",
        details: [{
          location: "north",
          foods: "foodTwo",
          mainCities: [
            "cityOne",
            "cityTwo",
            "cityThree"
          ]
        }]
      },
      countryThree: {
        weather: "weatherThree",
        details: [{
          location: "north",
          foods: "foodThree",
          mainCities: [
            "cityOne",
            "cityTwo",
            "cityThree"
          ]
        }]
      },
      countryFour: {
        weather: "WeatherFour",
        details: [{
          location: "west",
          foods: "foodFour",
          mainCities: [
            "cityOne",
            "cityTwo",
            "cityThree"
          ]
        }]
      },
      countryfive: {
        weather: "WeatherFive",
        details: [{
          location: "north",
          foods: "foodFive",
          mainCities: [
            "cityOne",
            "cityTwo",
            "cityThree"
          ]
        }]
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    filterByLocation: function(location) {
      return Object.values(this.continental).filter(v => v.details[0].location === location)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <h2>North locations</h2>
    <ol>
      <li v-for="loc in filterByLocation('north')" :key="loc.weather">
        {{loc.weather}}
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>West locations</h2>
    <ol>
      <li v-for="loc in filterByLocation('west')" :key="loc.weather">
        {{loc.weather}}
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! I guess I was overcomplicating things. Thank you so much!